# Regex to replace decimal number and all period in currency format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to make a regex to replace a decimal number and all period from a currency format ex. 60.000.00 to be 60000, 5.000.00 to be 5000. i have this regex below but it's not working like what i want. i really appreciate your help.

```
/([\.][0-9]*?$)/g
```

Comment: `60.000.00` isn't valid number format.

Comment: Remove the `.` characters, divide by 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your input format, the simplest way to achieve what you require would be to remove the `.` characters from the string, then divide the result by 100. Try this:

```js
['60.000.00', '5.000.00', '1.234.56'].forEach(function(value) {
  var output = value.replace(/\./g, '') / 100;
  console.log(output);
});
```

Comment: it's help me, you save my day.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution for your formation:

```js
console.log(format('600.000.00')); // Gives you 600000
function format(input){
    var regex = /(\d+\.)+/;
    var number = regex.exec(input);
    return number[0].toString().replace(/\./g,'');
}
```

Here is the RegEx example:[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KGIHQ9/1)

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex, use this:

```
var money = "";
money = "60.000.00";
money = money.replace(".", "");;
money = money.replace(".00", "")
document.writeln(money);
```